# Configure proxy in xmpp file transfer (Extension EXP-0065)

Tags: iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

```
 Server: testXyz  <br>
 Senderjid:user1@testXyz <br>
 Receiverjid:user2@testXyz

 RECV: 
 <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="C8B91358-179B-4883-9EEC-A251D99E9AB5" to="user1@testXyz" from="user2@testXyz/Spark 2.6.3" type="error">
 <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="C8B91358-179B-4883-9EEC-A251D99E9AB5" mode="tcp">
 <streamhost jid="proxy.Server" host="172.16.3.73" port="7777"/>
 </query><error code="406" type="MODIFY">
 <not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>`
```

I have set the 
`[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Server,nil]];`

From one of answer on stack overflow I came to know that On OpenFire, I needed to set the ip of the proxy using a system property of `xmpp.proxy.externalip`. But I have installed open fire on my one of machine of local network. 
So, what should be the value of  `xmpp.proxy.externalip` here this property?

Following already tried as a value of 'xmpp.proxy.externalip'
    1. PC's IP(local ip shown by ipconfig command)
    2. IP shown by what's myip website.

Any help would be appreciated.